# "val a:A = new B ", what's the point?

Tags: scala, types, type-inference

this idiom(?) appears quite a few times in the stairway book:

```
val b:A = new B
```

or

```
val b = new B
val b2:A = b
```

besides trying to make some points in a text book, why would you want to declare a type different than the inferred type of something?

By the way, any names for this?

Comment: I'd say this is called polymorphism

Comment: @maxmc But the object would still be polymorphic without it..

Comment: @maxmc Would you elaborate on how exactly this is polymorphisms :-? Like pst I a also believe this is not exactly what is meant by polymorphism ...

Comment: From wikipedia: "polymorphism is a programming language feature that allows values of different data types to be handled using a uniform interface." In your example 'A' is the uniform interface.

Answer (score 14):

It can be useful for:

1. Describing the programmer intent (*I created a B, but I'm interested only the A behavior*)
2. Ensuring that you will use only methods defined in A. It will allow to swap the concrete
    implementation later without having to change much of your code.
3. Simplifying the list of auto-completion available when using an IDE or
    the REPL.
4. Forcing an implicit conversion at some point.

For more complex instantiations, it ensures that the inferred type is the right one. For example

```
sealed trait Answer
case object Yes extends Answer
case object No extends Answer

scala> val a = List( Yes, Yes, No )
a: List[Product with Serializable with Answer] = List(Yes, Yes, No)

scala> val b: List[Answer] = List( Yes, Yes, No )
b: List[Answer] = List(Yes, Yes, No)
```

Answer (score 9):

I would argue that it is similar to the idiom of programming against interfaces. By doing

```
val b:A = new B
```

you make sure that after that point you're not relying on anything else than the interface provided by `A`. I.e., it guarantees that if you ever decide to change to `b:A = new C` nothing will break.

Comment: I believe it's called the Liskov substitution principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: I would say it's related, but different. By explicitly providing the type of `b` doesn't guarantee that the behavior of the program remains the same when going from `new B` to say `new C`. The Liskov substitution principle seems to be a more conceptual / higher notion.

Comment: This is called _type ascription_. By declaring `b: A` you're _ascribing_ the type `A` to a value of type `B`. You're effectively saying, "As far as I'm concerned, this thing is just an A". You could also write the declaration as `val b = new B : A`.

Comment: @AaronNovstrup +1 for "Type Ascription"